# Why does -9 & 0xaaaa get an unsigned result?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

The method convertToBinary is used to show the 8bit binary number,

```
public static String convertToBinary(int a){
    String binary="";
    for(int i=0;i<8;++i){
        Integer bit=new Integer(a&1);
        binary=bit.toString()+binary;
        a>>=1;
    }
    return binary;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=-9;
    System.out.println(convertBinary(a));            //11110111
    System.out.println(convertBinary(0xaaaa));       //10101010
    System.out.println(convertBinary(a&0xaaaa));     //10100010
    System.out.println(convertBinary((a&0xaaaa)>>1));//01010001
}
```

The last result prove that the result of `a&0xaaaa` is unsigned,can anyone explain why?

Comment: Don't confuse *positive* with *unsigned*.

Comment: The result of `a & b` is always smaller or equal than `min_u(a, b)` (where `min_u` is the unsigned minimum)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why positive?the most significant bit of (a&0xaaaa) is 1

Comment: The type of `a&0xaaaa` is `int`. Now reconsider your conclusion.

Comment: @Eagle_Fly `min_u(-9, 0xaaaa) = 0xaaaa`, which is clearly positive. The result can be no higher(unsigned), so any result must be positive.

Comment: You should change the  `for` loop to `for (int i=0;i<32;++i){`. That will clarify things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is an `int` and so is the literal `a&0xaaaa`. The result of the bitwise-and operation is also `int`. It has 32 bits. With

```
a&0xaaaa
```

you have masked out all but the lowest few bits from `a`. The result is a positive, 32-bit `int` value. So by printing out the lowest 8 bits of

```
(a&0xaaaa)>>1)
```

all you reveal is the value of the 9th bit in `a&0xaaaa`.

Note that the bit mask `0xaaaa`, even with the flawed assumption that it's no wider than the digits used, is still a 16-bit value and you are printing just the lower 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The last result does not prove that `>>` did an unsigned shift (saying that the value was unsigned is meaningless, values are just a bunch of bits, it's *operations* that are signed or unsigned).

Since you're only printing 8 bits, and so not looking at the 24 high bits, you have not seen the only bit that could be affected by the difference between `x >> 1` and `x >>> 1`, which is the highest bit. There wouldn't have been any difference between a signed shift and an unsigned shift, so based on that result you can not say which happened.

Comment: `saying that the value was unsigned is meaningless, values are just a bunch of bits`---not quite. `int` is defined as a *signed, two's complement 32-bit quantity*.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's a high-level illusion. You can easily interpret an `int` as unsigned, by making sure to only use signedness-invariant or unsigned operators on it. The top bit is in the end just a regular old bit.

Comment: It's high-level, but it's not an *illusion*---or, if you will, *everything* is an illusion, including you and me. There's just quantum wavefunction fluctuations.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Given a value, you cannot tell whether it is signed or not. It's purely an interpretation. That type `int` type is signed is all in the interpretation - ie, operators used on it which are different in the signed and unsigned case will be signed operators (except `>>>`, which is a special case).

Comment: We're not discussing values here, but the *static type of a Java expression*. In the world of static types, an `int` is a signed integer type. What you're stating is a simple truism: given a value, you can't tell if it's an `int`, a `float`, the higher half of a `long`, a bitset, or a Huffman-encoded string.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik well *I* was discussing the value, because that's what OP was looking at. I've never once mentioned the static type, so I don't know why you're pretending that that's what we're discussing. So yes it is a truism, which is why I was quite surprised to see you arguing about it :)

Comment: OP was certainly not looking at just a bunch of bits. He was looking at an instance of the Java `int` type, which is by specification a signed quantity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71953/discussion-between-harold-and-marko-topolnik).